# Snow leopard in vmware fusion

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-fusion, osx-lion

I'm on Lion and I want to install Snow Leopard in vmware fusion.
Is there a way to do that ?

Just want to do that, because of a software using powerpc not intel binaries.

Thanks !

Comment: Does Snow Leopard run PPC binaries?  I thought Leopard was the last one to do that?  I could be wrong.

Comment: Snow Leopard can do that with Rosetta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snow Leopard Client can be virtualized but it is forbiden. Doing so would breach the Apple User Agreement.

Comment: I saw with Lion, that they will change their politics.
I will wait a little :)

Comment: Lion client can be virtualized. 2 virtual machines instances are allowed per physical machines.

Comment: So, Lion can be installed in a virtual machine, but Snow Leopard, can't ?

Comment: Legally Yes. Lion can be virtualized as per the recents news. Snow Leopard cannot as per Apple User Agreement.

Technically both can be virtualized. Though Snow Leopard requires some hacking.

Comment: AFAIR Snow Leopard **Server** could be used in a VM